# Why doesn't Rust allow to implement external trait for external struct/enum? And what is the best whay to do it correct using Rust approach?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'd like to use an external trait for multiple libraries that returns vector of structs.

###### common_lib:

```
pub struct Post {
  pub title: String,
}

pub enum PostError {
  SourceError(String),
  Io(String),
}

#[async_trait]
pub trait PostGetter {
    async fn get_posts(&self) -> Result<Vec<Post>, PostError>;
}
```

But if I use an external structure for these purposes (which seems logical), then I will not be able to implement (for example) **From** trait for it. Because both From trait and Post/PostError  are external for my library

###### Try to use common_lib:

```
use std::io::Error;
use some::external::existing::data::strict::PostLike;

use common_lib::{Post, PostError};

// this code doesn't work
impl From<Error> for PostError {
    fn from(value: Error) -> Self {
        PostError::Io(value.to_string())
    }
}

// this code also doesn't work
impl From<PostLike> for Post {
    fn from(v: PostLike) -> Self {
        Post {
            title: v.title,
        }
    }
}
```

What is the right way to do it, from Rust philosophy point of view?

Comment: Put those trait impls in `common_lib`

Comment: You can find it in my general question titled by `common_lib:`

Comment: I was answering your question: The right way to do it in Rust is to put those trait impls in `common_lib`, where the types are defined.

Comment: If `common_lib` can't or won't implement an external trait, the Rust way is to wrap  usage of `common_lib::Error` in a _newtype_ such as `struct MyError(common_lib::Error)`, and implement the foreign trait on that newtype. Since newtype is defined by you, that is allowed. The newtype is a _zero-cost abstraction_: it will take the same amount of memory and be as fast as the original type.

Comment: Thank you, If you can vote on this question, it would be awesome if we publish it, because all existing questions are not the same, because doesn't contain such detailed description which you wrote

Comment: @Razzwan: Did you read the comments and answers to the duplicates? It's the same information there.

Comment: @ShadowRanger my question is what is the best way to do this, rather than trying to implement an external trait for the external library. That's the difference. But of course, if you think it's duplicated, I don't mind. Anyway, I solved my problem by refactoring the library and making it possible to implement the trait in the library dirrectly. This seems to be the best way in my case